# place light box over java applet

Tags: lightbox

i use lightbox for pop up thembs (in modal window)
in the same page i have an applet object showing 360 animated photos
when i click on any thumb the modal window is loded over the elements of the
page instead of the applet...

iknow the "hack" ( ) for flash objects but
it does not work for my java applet

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to position anything on top of an applet. However, there's a very ugly hack to do so.

More info: [Java Applet z-index on Safari and beyond](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638886/java-applet-z-index-problem-safari-and-beyond)