# Java applet 'covers' facebook dialogs

Tags: java, php, facebook, applet

When deploying an applet, (almost?) every facebook popup dialog is covered by the applet. The webpage is written in PHP, and the applet is deployed with applet tag. Results are the same with JNLP starter.

The error is present in the following browsers:

- Chrome - version 32.0.1700.107
- Opera - version 16.0.1196.62
- Opera - version 19.0.1326.59
- Internet Explorer - version 8.0.7600.16385
  It only seems to work well with Firefox (tested with version 27.0)

Screenshot:

[image]

On the screenshot the applet covers a chat window and the messages window. Is there any way to send the applet to the "background", so other panels become fully visible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The applet is deployed with _which_ tag? (Possible missing word in your message.) Also, what parameters are passed through this tag? I think we'd need some HTML and the JNLP contents here.

Comment: Sorry, that was really left out.
Used tag: applet.
The only parameter that is not used by the application is: name="separate_jvm" value="true"

Comment: How about width and height (i.e. `<applet code="MyClass.class" width="100" height="100">`)? Sounds like you should use those if your applet is oversized!

Comment: width="730" height="480", so it's not really oversized :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at these topics, you may find a solution there:

- [**How to display  over a Java applet in Chrome**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275953/how-to-display-div-over-a-java-applet-in-chrome)
- [**How to display pop-up content on top of an applet**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551479/how-to-display-pop-up-content-on-top-of-an-applet)
- [**Java Applet z-index on Safari and beyond**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638886/java-applet-z-index-on-safari-and-beyond)

Comment: I've tried setting the z-index, but it didn't work, as I have no control over the source of the facebook page

Comment: Hiding the applet seems a good idea, but how can I detect when a user clicks outside of my applet (or even outside my side of the webpage)?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I accepted your reply as solution